# invalid conversion from void* to strcut* in c++

Tags: c++, structure, calloc

when i try to use calloc for continuous memory allocation it gives me error like.. 
invalid conversion from void* to slotstruct(*)[100][1500] in c++

here is my code :

```
typedef struct
 {
   int id;
   bool used;
 }slotstruct;
 int main(){
       slotstruct ( *slot1 )[100][1500];
       slot1 = calloc( 1, 3 * sizeof( *slot1 ) );
      for(i=0;i<3;i++){
         for(j=0;j<100;j++){
            for(k=0;k<1500;k++){
                  cout << "Addresses are : "<<slot1[i][j][k];
           }
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your code can not compile, is it really the code you get error?

Comment: @appleapple Read the first sentence in the question. The code not compiling is *exactly* why this was posted.

Comment: @WhozCraig no, it not compile for a lot other reason than what the OP ask

Comment: Off topic: `typedef struct {} slotstruct` is unnecessary in C++ . `struct slotstruct` would be sufficient.

Comment: @WhozCraig example: `i,j,k` is not declared, no `include`s and `using`s, finally what the OP ask for

Comment: if this is really the code OP use, the first error would be `calloc was not declared in this scope` or something like

Comment: you should use `new` and `delete` in c++ programs unless you have good reasons

Comment: Also off topic: `calloc` is dangerous in C++. It will not invoke constructors. It works here because your structure is trivial, but be warned. In C++ one cannot simply assign `void *` You must state you are deliberately doing something potentially stupid with a cast.

Comment: Oh, and OP can't cout `slotstruct` without any other code.

Comment: @appleapple OP isn't trying to output `slotstruct`. OP wants the address but neglected to use the address of operator.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes you are right, I miss that point.

Comment: Don't too much conversation here.. Use chat room for long conversation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C language allows implicit conversion (without casts) of `void*` to any other object pointer type. Such is not the case in C++. Your options are:

- Don't compile C code with a C++ compiler (easiest).
- Perform the proper cast to avoid the error (ill advised, casts, especially for beginners, are often used to *hide* problems rather than *solve* them. Abuse of them for that very purpose is, unfortunately, not uncommon. It would, however, "solve" your issue here).
- Use `new[]` and `delete[]` for your sequence allocation. No casting is required, and if your data type ever becomes non-trivial, it will still work.
- Don't use manual memory allocation *at all*, and instead opt for an RAII approach.

The first of these is obvious, the rest are shown below

---

**Using a cast**

Will work in this case with no ill effects because your `slotstruct` type is trivial:

```
slot1 = (slotstruct (*)[100][1500])calloc( 1, 3 * sizeof( *slot1 ) ); // allocates
free(slot1); // destroys
```

**Using `new[]` (and `delete[]`)**

No cast required:

```
slot1 = new slotstruct[3][100][1500]; // allocates..
delete [] slot1; //.. destroys
```

**C++ Alternative using [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)**

A more proper C++ RAII approach for what you appear to be trying to accomplish looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

struct slotstruct
{
    int id;
    bool used;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::array<std::array<slotstruct,1500>, 100>> slots(3);

    for (auto const& x : slots)
        for (auto const& y : x)
            for (auto const& z : y)
                std::cout <<"Address is : " << static_cast<const void*>(&z) << '\n';
}
```

Output (varies)

```
Address is : 0x100200000
Address is : 0x100200008
Address is : 0x100200010
Address is : 0x100200018
Address is : 0x100200020
...
Address is : 0x10056ee60
Address is : 0x10056ee68
Address is : 0x10056ee70
Address is : 0x10056ee78
```

Comment: Man. I wish I'd seen this go up. Would have gone to bed half an hour ago. Only thing I'd add is a quick note on why `'\n'` and not `endl`, and I'd change the inner most `auto const& x` to `auto const& z` or similar to prevent confusion over the duplicated variable name.

Comment: @user4581301 duh. I totally spaced on the `z`. The '\n' is, in a continual effort, to remind myself that unnecessary direct flushing requests is something that should be avoided. Sutter and Stroustrup talk about it briefly in the [Core C++ Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rio-endl). Thanks the for catching the innermost index.

Answer (score 0):

Only for what you ask: You should explicit do the type cast from void* to others in c++ programs.

And you should consider using `new` and `delete` instead.